# startActivity not working 2

Tags: java, android

For some reason `startActivity`is working in one of my classes but not another. It's a bit much but I've included my whole non-working class below. (minus imports and such)

```
public class question1 {

    private Button Next;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstancesState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question_1, container, false);
        return view;


    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Next = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button4);

        Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(question1.this, question2.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to extend Activity

Comment: Is this a Fragment? `onCreateView` is defined for Fragments. If so, you should have `class question1 extends Fragment` instead

Answer (score 2):

`startActivity()` only works for `Activity` not simple classes.

Change

```
public class question1 {
```

to

```
public class question1 extends Activity {
```

or

```
public class question1 extends AppCompatActivity {
```

as per your needs.

Same goes for `question2` class also.

Comment: Like @Rohit5k2 said and maybe AppCompatActivity.

Comment: @Stanojkovic - Maybe? AppCompatActivity extends Activity...

Comment: No  @cricket_007, public class question1 extends AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Your class should extend activity..
And you should also have to include this class into androidmenifest.xml file